# cv2.drawMatches is missing from 2.4.9?

Tags: python, opencv

I am using opencv 2.4.9 (latest git branch origin/2.4)

```
img3 = cv2.drawMatches(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,good,None,**draw_params)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'drawMatches'
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: above code is for opencv3.0, not 2.4.9

Comment: @berak, thanks. so the 2.4.9 has no cv2.drawMatches? only c++ version?

Comment: no  drawMatches fpr python in 2.4.9, correct. if you're desperate/daring, you could try to change CV_EXPORTS to CV_EXPORTS_W [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4/modules/features2d/include/opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp#L1490) but i can't promise anything, might be just a waste of time.. (also, branch before touching the src)

Comment: @berak, why `CV_EXPORTS_W` will help? It seems only an alias of `__declspec(dllexport)` ? Well, there probably are some good reasons why they did not expose this to cv2, I guess it might be better just draw those lines directly. Thanks!

Comment: hehe, yea it does nothing in c++. it's a marker for the generator scripts to include it ;) on the other hand, true, far better just roll your own drawing, instead of messing with the guts of opencv ...

Comment: @berak, thanks for pointing it out. I just read the py_bindings_basics. Seems like the `CV_EXPORTS_W` `CV_EXPORTS_AS` might do the trick.

Comment: CV_EXPORTS_AS(alt_name) is for when you need to give it a name different from the original

Comment: there are 2 drawMatches. It seems like CV_EXPORTS_AS is required for handle Overloaded functions.

Comment: yes, since python does not know overloading